# Best way to do aggregations in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm running out of memory when I try to do this aggregation. It works fine, but very slow on a small subset of data. I'm running this in pySpark. Is there an alternative way to take the average of a column based on a specific group that would run better?

```
df = df.groupBy("id", "timestamp").avg("accel_lat", "accel_long", "accel_vert")
```

Comment: This is pretty much as efficient as it gets.  In < 2.0.0 you can gain a little by using "old style" scheduling but that's it. If it is particularly slow it rather suggests some configuration issues.

Answer (score 0):

The only other thing that I can think of is the data structure of id and timestamp. Make sure those two are not strings. Try to reduce the size of the type or change the schema of df.